# Solving HJ equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I was solving some PDEs but I don't have ideas on how to solve this:

$\begin{cases} \phi_t+H \left (\phi_x,\phi_y \right )=0 \\ \phi(x,y,0)=\phi_0=cos\left (\pi\left (x+y\right )\right )\end{cases}$

with $H \left (\phi_x,\phi_y \right )=\phi_x+\phi_y$. It seems very simple but I can't solve it...

I thinked $\phi(x,y,dt)=\phi_0+dt \left[ -2\pi sin\left( \pi\left(x+y\right )\right ) \right]$

but maybe It is not a good way

Comment: Hint: Transport equation.

Comment: You are right @GiuseppeNegro, I have to use method of lines (or Characteristics)... but I know it only in 1D. Do you know some source where I can read about 2D? (ita or eng)

Comment: You don't need the full method here, this is an easy case. See Evans's book on PDE in the very first pages (transport equation).